# Prove that $F(t)$ is continuous at $0$

Tags: integration, continuity

> Let $F(t)=\int_{0}^{\infty}f(t,x)dx$ with $f(t,x)=\dfrac{1-e^{-tx^2}}{x^2}$
>   Prove that $F$ is continuousat $0$.

**My proof:**

We have the inequality $1-e^{-y}\le \min(1,y), \forall y \ge 0$

Thus $f(t,x) \le t,\forall x\in[0,1]$ and $f(t,x)\le \dfrac{1}{x^2},\forall x\in [1,+\infty)$.

We have $g(x)=\int_{0}^{1}tdx$ and $h(x)=\int_{1}^{+\infty}\dfrac{1}{x^2}$ are integrable. 
Thus we have $\int_{0}^{\infty}f(t,x)dx\le g(x)+h(x)$

Applying the theorem of dominated convergence, we have 
$\lim_{t\to0}F(t)=\lim_{t\to0}\int_{0}^{\infty}f(t,x)dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}\lim_{t\to0}f(t,x)dx=0$

Moreover $F(0)=0$. Hence $\lim_{t\to0}F(t)=F(0)$ of F is continuous at $0$.

I don't use theorem of continuity for parameter-integral here.

Is my proof right or wrong?

Comment: The idea with dominated convergence is correct, but the execution is a bit sloppy. The line `We have $g(x)=\int_0^1tdx$ and $h(x)=\int_1^\infty \frac 1{x^2}$ are integrable. ` is not correct mathematically (for instance $\int_0^1 t\,dx$ can not depend on $x$, here $x$ is an integration variable).

Comment: A more correct way would be to say that if $|t|<1$, then $$f(t,x)\le \begin{cases}1,&x\le 1\\\frac{1}{x^2},&x\ge1\end{cases}$$ and proceed as before.